# Why are the indexes of Scala tuples 1-based?

Tags: scala

"*Programming In Scala*" explains that tuples'

> _N numbers are one-based, instead of zero-based, because starting with 1 is
>   a tradition set by other languages
>   with statically typed tuples such as
>   Haskell and ML

but this can hardly be called *an explanation*.

Why were tuples defined as 1-based in Haskell and ML in the first place?
Are there any mathematical/programming benefits in having 1-based indexed tuples and not 0-based?

Thanks,
Ori

Comment: 1-based indexing has been mathematically proven to be faster.

Comment: @pelotom, I'd say 0-based is faster. The only difference is that in 1-based you'll for instance write 10 instead of 9 for the 10th element. And 10 is one more character to read and parse than 9! ;-)

Comment: @aioobe: of course, "10" is *much* slower to parse than "9", but how often are you accessing the 10th element of a tuple? For the common case, "1" provides much faster access to the first element of the tuple, due the simple fact that it requires fewer pixels to draw than "0".

Comment: Weird to me that nothing in this thread mentions that Scala's one-based Tuples seem inconsistent with its zero-based Arrays and Lists.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I guess `_1`, `_2` etc it is short for "first", "second", and so on. (`fst` and `snd` for instance have historically been used for accessing the left and right part of a tuple). The index in an array on the other hand is an *offset* and the first element is usually at offset 0.

> ***Are there any mathematical/programming benefits in having 1-based indexed tuples and not 0-based?***

No. The elements are not accessed programatically anyway. (You can't do `_i` if `i` is an integer.)

Comment: All correct until the last sentence. The elements can be accessed programmatically using Product.productElement(n) ... with n 0-based, so for example tuple.productElement(3)==tuple._4

Comment: Right, but then, as you say, it's 0 based. The 1-based `_i` notation isn't programatically accessible.

Comment: True. Luckily, I'd say: working with 1-based indexes is small nightmare (did it in the 80s with some flavours of Basic).

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps Haskell and ML used 1-based tuples because [COBOL, Algol, and FORTRAN used 1-based arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list). Tradition is a funny thing...

Comment: Algol68 permitted the programmer to index an array from any lower bound, the default was 1.  c.f. Van Wijngaarden: '' “Let me sell you a language”, he started, and proceeded to outline the ideas behind the language. He showed some examples. “Can you deﬁne triangular arrays?” someone (Tony Hoare?) interrupted. “Not just triangular, but even elliptical” replied Aad, and showed how.'' from "The Making of ALGOL 68" http://www.cs.ru.nl/~kees/home/papers/psi96.pdf

Answer (score 4):

0 based things are great when you want to do math with the index. It just doesn't work with 1 based indexes.

Yet for everybody but computer geeks 1 based is much more natural.

Tuples are intended to contain completely different things. So doing something like add the index of this element and add it to the index of that element and obtain the element with the resulting index don't make sense for tuples.

Therefore I'd say tuples are 1 based, because it is the natural thing to do and there is no reason not to do it.

Comment: Well, the users of Scala tuples *are* "computer geeks" :) 
The outcome of having two types of indexing schemes in the same language this is that there is yet one more thing to remember, which I find a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I guess since tuple is fixed length, defined by user and mostly important is that it's indexed by user, so tuple is 1 based index.
Array/List, on the contrary, is indexed by computer (we often index list with `list[i]` and the `i` is calculated by Math), so 0 based index is easier.

Just my own guess. Don't know if it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Because starting with 1 is a tradition set by other languages with statically typed tuples, such as Haskell and ML.